Does legacy x86 (before Intel-VT and AMD-SVM) supports Type 1 Hypervisor?
I am familiar with the dynamic translation and the trap-and-emulate (Type1 Hypervisor) concepts. What makes me confused is that many articles usually combine dynamic translation and type 1 hypervisor, like the following the figure.

In my opinion, when using dynamic translation (e.g., qemu), we usually emulate a set of fake CPU registers and update them based on guest instructions, which means the emulated code usually has the same privilege mode as the hypervisor. But for type 1 hypervisor, they should be in different privileged modes.
Therefore, I wonder before Intel-VT/AMD-SVM (hardware-assisted virtualization) shows up, does legacy x86 support type 1 hypervisor? If yes, how does it emulate sensitive instructions that failed to raise traps across different privileges?

how is machine-virtualization achieved without hardware support mentions a VMware document about practical x86 stuff.  The image you included looks like a grayscale version of figure 5 from that paper.

Yes, thanks. But this whitepaper doesn't describe how to emulate across privilege modes.

Basically no, x86 doesn't "support" virtualization.  It's inconvenient to virtualize transparently; when you binary-translate code that accesses EFLAGS, you might need to replace popf with more instructions using scratch space outside what the guest normally has mapped, or trap to a hypervisor / emulator.

"But for type 1 hypervisor, they should be in different privileged modes.", the original paper where Type I and Type II VMM are introduced, doesn't impose this constraint. It also doesn't consider dynamic translation. In short, x86 set of sensitive instructions is not a subset of the privileged instructions (e.g. sgdt) and without hardware assisted virtualization you need dynamic translation.


Does legacy x86 support type 1 hypervisor?

Yes, it does.

If yes, how does it emulate sensitive instructions that failed to raise traps across different privileges?

By using binary translation: the sensitive instructions are replaced with other instructions that emulate the behavior of the sensitive instructions properly.
